# Order of keys and values in maps

Tags: clojure

When we call keys on a map, is the order of keys in the resulting seq guaranteed to be the same as the order of values when we call vals on the same map?

In other words, is it ok to map a function f over the contents of a map like this:

```
(map #(f %1 %2) (keys m) (vals m))
```

If not, is there an equivalent to perl's each in clojure? Or perhaps the inverse function of zipmap?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clojure's maps: are keys and vals in same order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772384/clojures-maps-are-keys-and-vals-in-same-order)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can iterate over the map, you get key val pairs,

```
(map (fn [[key val]]
       (println key val)) {:a :b :c :d})
```

pretty much all clojure data structures are seqable.

Comment: `(for [[k v] {:a :b :c :d}] (println k v))` is rather nicer - I try to avoid writing `(map (fn ...))` when possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Hamza, and thanks for the elegant example amalloy. Just out of curiosity, back to my original question, is the assumption that keys and vals return elements in the same order correct?

Comment: @Stefanos, unless it is a sorted map, iteration order may change so AFAICT same applies for vals keys also.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772384/clojures-maps-are-keys-and-vals-in-same-order