# Clojure's maps: are keys and vals in same order?

Tags: clojure, hashmap

Is it ok to rely on
`(= m (zipmap (keys m) (vals m)))`
in Clojure 1.3+?

Having this behavior makes for slightly more readable code in some situations, eg

```
(defn replace-keys [smap m]
  (zipmap (replace smap (keys m)) (vals m)))
```

vs.

```
(defn replace-keys [smap m]
  (into {} (for [[k v] m] [(smap k k) v]))
```

Comment: Generally speaking I don't think its a good idea to consider "position" in case of a map data structure

Comment: In 2013, is this considered an implementation detail or a promise?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I can confirm (officially) that the answer to this is yes. The docstrings for `keys` and `vals` were updated in Clojure 1.6 to mention this (see http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1302).

Answer (score 20):

Yes, lots of clojure would break if that changed.

Maps are stored as trees and both functions walk the same tree in the same order.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere, or just an implementation detail that could change?

Comment: Check out [this question](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/clojure/s1sFVF7dAVs) over at Clojure's Google group. It's practically the identical question, even down to wording.